# Program hangs on channel rx

Tags: rust

Could somebody explain, why if I remove the "move" from for_each, the program hangs?

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
fn main() {
    let v = vec![0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    let (tx, rx) = channel();
    v.iter().for_each(move |&elem| {
        tx.send(elem).unwrap();
    });
    println!("Tx'ed");

    let rx_vec: Vec<_> = rx.iter().collect();

    println!("Collected into vec");
}
```

Comment: Please make a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I did. It is in my OP.

Comment: No it is not. What is `v`? And I can only guess that `channel()` refers to `std::sync::mpsc::channel()`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Fair enough, will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code hangs without `move` because in that variant `tx` never gets dropped so the channel isn't closed so the `rx` waits indefinitely for additional data, you can just `drop(tx)` before `rx.iter()` to close the channel.