# Thread cannot end normally

Tags: rust

I have the following Rust code, 1 input/output thread and 10 worker threads, however this code seems to be blocking and never ends, can anyone tell me how to fix it?

```
use crossbeam_channel::bounded;
use crossbeam_utils::thread;

fn worker() -> usize {
    thread::scope(|work| {
        let (in_s, in_r) = bounded(10);
        let (ou_s, ou_r) = bounded(10);
        work.spawn(move |_| {
            //input thread
            for i in 0..100 {
                in_s.send(i).unwrap();
            }
        });


        (0..10).for_each(|_| {
            let in_r = in_r.clone();
            let ou_s = ou_s.clone();
            work.spawn(move |_| {
                //worker thread
                while let Ok(i) = in_r.recv() {
                    ou_s.send(i+1).unwrap();
                }
            });
        });

        work.spawn(move |_| {
            //output thread
            let mut total = 0;
            while let Ok(res) = ou_r.recv() {
                total += res;
            }
            total
        }).join().unwrap()
    }).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let total = worker();
}
```

Comment: You're not disconnecting your output channel, meaning you'll spin forever. This behaivour is documented [here](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/channel/struct.Receiver.html#method.recv). You need to drop `ou_s` once you're done with it, e.g. once you've finished receiving events from your input channel in your worker thread.

Comment: Same underlying problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77401901/442760) even though the exact implementation is a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the send part of each channel when you've finished using it. Otherwise `crossbeam` assumes that you may still send something through it and calls to the corresponding `recv` will block. In your case, see the added comments below:

```
use crossbeam_channel::bounded;
use crossbeam_utils::thread;

fn worker() -> usize {
    thread::scope(|work| {
        let (in_s, in_r) = bounded(10);
        let (ou_s, ou_r) = bounded(10);
        work.spawn(move |_| {
            //input thread
            for i in 0..100 {
                in_s.send(i).unwrap();
            }
            // `in_s` is dropped automatically when the thread ends
        });
        // The original `in_s` was moved into the thread, then closed when the
        // thread ended -> `in_r.recv()` will return `Err` after the last element
        // has been received

        (0..10).for_each(|_| {
            let in_r = in_r.clone();
            let ou_s = ou_s.clone();
            work.spawn(move |_| {
                //worker thread
                while let Ok(i) = in_r.recv() {
                    ou_s.send(i+1).unwrap();
                }
                // The `ou_s` clone owned by this thread is dropped automatically
                // when the thread ends
            });
        });
        // `ou_s` was cloned and the clones were moved into the worker threads. Each
        // clone will be closed when the thread finishes, but the original `ou_s` is
        // still live so calling `ou_r.recv()` would block in case we used the
        // original `ou_s` to send more data. We need to close it explicitly:
        drop (ou_s); // <-- Add this

        work.spawn(move |_| {
            //output thread
            let mut total = 0;
            while let Ok(res) = ou_r.recv() {
                total += res;
            }
            total
        }).join().unwrap()
    }).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let total = worker();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=2d7172501de09af50be0bff517e3a286)